# PL/SQL Oracle Trigger Before Insert Can't get New Unique Primary ID

Tags: oracle, plsql

Whats wrong...?? Please check my trigger

```
create or replace
TRIGGER TBL_AE_BI
BEFORE UPDATE
ON TBL_AE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
KD_AE VARCHAR2 (6);

BEGIN

  SELECT AE_ID INTO KD_AE FROM (
  SELECT KDMAX,(SELECT TO_CHAR('AE')KD FROM DUAL)||
        (CASE WHEN KDMAX>=0 AND  KDMAX<10 THEN '000'||KDMAX
              WHEN KDMAX>=10 AND  KDMAX<100 THEN '00'||KDMAX
              WHEN KDMAX>=100 AND  KDMAX<1000 THEN '0'||KDMAX
              ELSE TO_CHAR(KDMAX)
         END)AE_ID
  FROM (SELECT (NVL(MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(AE_ID,3,4))),0)+1)KDMAX FROM TBL_AE)
  );

  :NEW.AE_ID:=KD_AE;
  :NEW.INSERT_DATE:= SYSDATE; 

END;
```

When I insert a new record into the table, result is error with cannot insert NULL to AE_ID.

But when I execute in SQL window with the following code

```
SELECT AE_ID as KD_AE FROM (
SELECT KDMAX,(SELECT TO_CHAR('AE')KD FROM DUAL)||
  (CASE WHEN KDMAX>=0 AND  KDMAX<10 THEN '000'||KDMAX
        WHEN KDMAX>=10 AND  KDMAX<100 THEN '00'||KDMAX
        WHEN KDMAX>=100 AND  KDMAX<1000 THEN '0'||KDMAX
        ELSE TO_CHAR(KDMAX)
   END)AE_ID
FROM (SELECT (NVL(MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(AE_ID,3,4))),0)+1)KDMAX FROM TBL_AE)
)
```

result is no error, and I get a new unique ID.

Like

Comment: The trigger is `BEFORE UPDATE` not before insert and the trigger will not fire when insert new data

Comment: Additionally, building a trigger to create the next key based on existing data in the table is incorrect.  It won't work in a multiuser system-- multiple sessions will generate the same `ae_id`.  It will throw a mutating table exception if you ever do an `insert select`.  If you wanted to do something like that, you'd at a minimum need to introduce something to control concurrency to ensure that only one session could be inserting rows at a time.  That would make your system highly inefficient and non-scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change BEFORE UPATE to BEFORE INSERT

```
create or replace
TRIGGER TBL_AE_BI
BEFORE INSERT --Changed
ON TBL_AE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
KD_AE VARCHAR2 (6);

BEGIN

  SELECT AE_ID INTO KD_AE FROM (
  SELECT KDMAX,(SELECT TO_CHAR('AE')KD FROM DUAL)||
        (CASE WHEN KDMAX>=0 AND  KDMAX<10 THEN '000'||KDMAX
              WHEN KDMAX>=10 AND  KDMAX<100 THEN '00'||KDMAX
              WHEN KDMAX>=100 AND  KDMAX<1000 THEN '0'||KDMAX
              ELSE TO_CHAR(KDMAX)
         END)AE_ID
  FROM (SELECT (NVL(MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(AE_ID,3,4))),0)+1)KDMAX FROM TBL_AE)
  );

  :NEW.AE_ID:=KD_AE;
  :NEW.INSERT_DATE:= SYSDATE; 

END;
```